# Expo Build, Automatically updates my live app on app store and playstore

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi everytime I run `expo:build ios` my clients who has existing app also is getting my update?

Do you know how to fix this?

I want to submit to appstore first and then they update from appstore before they could get my update.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

```
"updates": {
   "enabled": false
}
```

to your `app.json`. At least that's how I've done it in the past. There's new `expo-updates` package, which gives you more control over your updates. You can check that out [here](https://docs.expo.io/bare/updating-your-app/#configuration-options).

You will have to republish your app to play store after you change your `app.json`.

Comment: Hi, giotskhada. I'd like to ask what's the benefit of having this feature. I mean why did expo enabled it by default. Isn't it bad to have 2 version source at the same time?

Comment: Hi @giotskhada,  I'd like to ask what's the benefit of having this feature. I mean why did expo enabled it by default. Isn't it bad to have 2 version source at the same time?

Comment: It's for convenience. You rebuild your app and it updates automatically without any additional hustle. If you'd like to use this feature you should have separate development and production branches for your project and only push to production when you feel the update is ready. I personally choose to disable it.

Comment: Hi @giotskhada, i tried doing this but the update is still being fetched automatically